# Print Statement speech marks causing syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

So I am writing a basic leaderboard/score tracker for reasons that don't need to be said, at the closing bracket on one of my print statements there is a syntax error. I am not new to programming but I'm not too great at it. I'm here to learn!

I haven't tried much but I have done some research on the problem and I found something similar to my problem but I couldn't wrap my head around what they meant, if a nice simple explanation could be given that would be great!

```
score1 = ("Enter the score for",player1": ")              
score2 = ("Enter the score for",player2": ")
```

I expect the speech mark to not cause a syntax error as it seems normal to me and should (I think) not cause a problem. But the closing speech mark on the top line of code is causing a syntax error. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: what are score1 and score2? Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the , between player1 and the :

The reason for the error is that there's nothing separating the variable and the string

```
score1 = ("Enter the score for", player1, ": ")
score2 = ("Enter the score for", player2, ": ")
```

Also, you need to put input at the start of each so it can receive information

```
score1 = input("Enter the score for", player1, ": ")
score2 = input("Enter the score for", player2, ": ")
```